# How to remove header part of output from sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I have a `data.frame` and want to get mean of every column. I applied `sapply` and got the following

```
Hour       Minute     TotalDay    TotalHour
0.00        17.33       105.93      2542.41
```

I want to remove the header part of the output from `sapply` so that it looks like:

```
0.00        17.33       105.93      2542.41
```

Any help on how I can do that is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That's not reproducible at all. But chances are you have a named vector. do and `str` on it and check.

Comment: would this not also be a good use of `colMeans()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(code pasting into comment wasn't working as well as I'd've liked). Again, isn't this what `colMeans()` was designed to do? Would be easier to reproduce if more code/data was in the original q.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = sample(1000,10), y = sample(1000,10), z = sample(1000,10)) 

print(dat)
##      x   y   z
## 1  565 374  88
## 2  347 688 896
## 3  478 542 508
## 4  103 350 122
## 5  115  61 175
## 6  573 164 543
## 7  371 304 486
## 8  437 659 140
## 9  532 510  61
## 10  47 227 738

print(as.numeric(colMeans(dat)))
## [1] 356.8 387.9 375.7
```

As Ananda Mahto pointed out in the comments (but something I assumed would be obvious after someone unfamiliar with `colMeans()` did a `?colMeans` in the R console (we don't just cut/paste code from Stack*, right? :-) `colMeans()` isn't stripping labels, the `as.numeric()` is. I pointed out `colMeans()` primarily to suggest avoiding `*apply()` calls for column means where there are built-in alternatives. Yes, there are times when doing an `*apply()` for column means would make sense, but definitely not in this case (IMO).

Comment: Perhaps you need to update your answer to indicate that `colMeans()` doesn't discard the names. The `as.numeric` part is where the removal of the names is happening.

Comment: +1 for the edit, except for the part about assuming that anything is obvious.... My point about posting my comment is that you're actually answering a different question, which is totally valid, but would not necessarily be helpful to someone who stumbles across this question when looking to avoid `sapply`'s behavior with a different function--especially considering the question's title. Also, why did you use `as.numeric` and not simply `as.vector` if we know the output is already numeric?

Answer (score 5):

There are way better choices with `colMeans` but I personally like `lapply` and `unlist` in many circumstances and for stubborn hard to kill names the `use.names = FALSE` argument to `unlist` as follows (using mtcars data set as you provided none):

```
unlist(lapply(mtcars, mean), use.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one alternative: Just set assigng `NULL` value to `names`

```
> output <- sapply(iris[,-5], mean)
> names(output) <- NULL
> output
[1] 5.843333 3.057333 3.758000 1.199333
```